# Tips for benchmarking and load testing web server?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, load-testing, benchmark

I'm trying to benchmark and load test various web server setups (mod_php vs php as fastcgi, max/min worker/thread configuration, and so on). I'm starting with ab, but would be interested in other recommended tools for this job. The web server is a Linux server, but I can run Windows based testing tools from my desktop machine if need be.

I'm also interested in any recommendations as to technique. For example:

- I'm assuming I'll get more useful results running from a separate machine doing nothing else (as opposed to running on the same machine as the web server, or on my desktop machine as a background process). Is this correct?
- Likewise, I figure I can reduce the effects of network issues on the testing by putting that machine in the same data center on a private IP.
- I'll want to setup more than just a single file to get any sort of real test (can I even do this with ab?).

Any other tips?

Comment: +1 very good question where this kinda of test may help you to best tune your webserver.

Answer (score 2):

I like to set up a classroom of computers who run [siege](http://freshmeat.net/projects/siege/).

I crawl the website once using wget

```
wget -r -l0 -np -O /dev/null http://domainname.com
// Note that the -l0 means that it will recurse infinitly, depending on your site, 
// you might want to change that to something lower, say ... -l3
// This will crawl the site, and throw all the contents away.
```

Then I fetch all the unique URLs from the serverlogs by using a oneliner like this:

```
awk '{ print "http://domainname.com"$7 }' access.log | sort | uniq
```

Then siege can be set up to use this file, and will then attempt them in random order.

```
siege -f siegeurls -i -b
```

It can also be configured to send various headers, set useragent and whatnot.

I'd recommend that you take a look at siege. This is the setup I use when I test website-rigs myself.

Comment: Please provide some links to your proposed solution.

Comment: Could only add one link because of my reputation. I added some more information about what I do.

Comment: Nice. If only I had a classroom. :)

Comment: Well, you can do the exact same things locally on the server itself, or "use what you have" in the network.

We use a classroom when we want to simulate loads that are heavy for Norwegian websites. E.g. ~200k requests per second. How much traffic do you want the rig to be able to handle?